# Sqlite database entry to csv

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, csv

Hello friends i need your Help please.

I have create a app that save some information from the app into a sqlite database. This database have 4 rows. Now i want to put the content of the database into a csv data programmatically. I have done create a csv data and put 1 of the database row into the csv but it always overwrites the first row an do not put all the 4 rows of the database into the csv.

Thanks for your Help. In the following ist code:

```
    NSMutableArray *arra = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //NSMutableArray *arra1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //NSMutableArray *arra2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_ansDB, query_csv, -1, &csvStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while (sqlite3_step(csvStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            [arra addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(csvStmt,0)]];
            //[arra1 addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(csvStmt,1)]];
            //[arra2 addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(csvStmt,2)]];


            // Spalte Gut --> CSV
            NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myCsv.csv"];
            NSString *fileGut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];

            [[arra componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]writeToFile:fileGut atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: Are all 4 rows being retrieved from the database and stored in the array correctly?

Comment: Yes i have do it so :[arra addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(csvStmt,0)]];                                   Have you a example maybe?

Comment: I don't understand your response.  Is the data correct in `arra`?

Comment: Sorry, Yes it is correct ! in arra is the first row of the sqlite database, put this into a csv data work fine but how can i put another row of the database into the csv in the next free row of the csv?

Comment: So are you asking how to append to an existing file rather than overwriting it?